# Specific sort items of an array

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, indexing, replace

Let's assume I have an array of 3 items, they are created randomly. One of them has popular boolean: true, and the rest of them don't.
I want to put the popular item as index 1 (centered)
like so [example, popular, example]

I tried to sort like this

```
 items.sort((a, b) => {
   if (a.id < b.id) {
     return -1;
   }
   if (a.id > b.id) {
     return 1;
   }
   return 0;
 });
```

but in this case, I have to add to all those 3 items specific ID (from 1 to 3)
for some reason, I can't give them IDs, so this solution is not gonna work as needed.

Comment: You could `find` the `true` item and `splice` it to `index = 1` instead of `sort`.

Comment: Is it always 3 items? Can there be multiple `true` items? Sort sure seems like overkill

Comment: @slappy always 3 items, created randomly.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov this array generates on the server

Comment: If it's just three, then it's a mere index swap. Like if `true` was at index `0`, it would be: `[items[0], items[1]] = [items[1], items[0]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's always three items, just iterate the array, find the `true` one, and swap its index with index `1`.

```js
const items = [
  {x: false},
  {x: false},
  {x: true},
];

for (const [i, o] of items.entries()) {
  if (o.x) {
    [items[i], items[1]] = [items[1], items[i]];
    break;
  }
}

console.log(items);
```

Or since there are really just two possibilities, you could do it without the loop.

```js
const items = [
  {x: false},
  {x: false},
  {x: true},
];

var idx = items[0].x ? 0 :
          items[2].x ? 2 :
                       1;

[items[idx], items[1]] = [items[1], items[idx]];

console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for `popular` in the sorter and use appropriate return if one of them has the true boolean, otherwise return based on id.

```js
data.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.popular || b.popular) {
    return a.popular ? -1 : 1;
  }
  return a.id - b.id;
});

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script>
const data = [
  {id:4},
  {id:2},
  {id:3,  popular:true},
  {id:1}
]
</script>
```